# Joomla URL rewriting in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, joomla, content-management-system, joomla3.0

I'm using Joomla for my blog and i trying to rewriting my portfolio url but i can't find any guide to transform a url like this:

```
mysite.com/component/mb2portfolio/project/80-roberta-fabio.html

to: mysite.com/reportage-matrimonio/roberta-fabio.html
```

I use Joomla 3.4.8 and the component that i use is Mb2 Portfolio.

Can anyone please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: The problem here is that both those URIs do not share anything in common, except for the `roberta-fabio.html` part. You could rewrite each portfolio page/item/project indivisually with `mod_rewrite`, but that will become very cumbersome very quickly.

Comment: i if understand correctly you say the the url i can transform my url in this form: reportage-matrimonio/matrimonio/roberta-fabio.html !! Can you show how can do this kind of rewriting

Comment: What I am saying is that you could hard-code each rewrite like this: `RewriteRule ^reportage-matrimonio/roberta-fabio.html$ /component/mb2portfolio/project/80-roberta-fabio.html [L]`, but that would be cumbersome because you would have to do it for every URI. Also, you would need to make sure that your template outputs the correct URLs.